# How to bundle 6 msi into one msi installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, dotnetinstaller

I have 6 msi that I want to bundle into single msi package. These 6 are office addin, out of these 3 are for office 2003 and 3 for office 2007. So my single msi should install only 3 addon based on the version of office. And there are some prerequisites that i want to install before these msi.

I  tried using wix for once it created a setup but after sometime same project gave error: "Error 1 Unresolved reference to symbol 'ChainPackageGroup:wwwwww' in section 'Bundle:wixB2'" . 
Setup creted by wix was able to install the setups but was not able to uninstall them, may be uninstallation needed admin rights but i was not able to give.

I also tried dotnetinstaller but i could not find how to add launch condition for my 6 installers. (Inatllcheck in dotnetinstaller only checks existense of the product getting install not the launch condition) If anybody can tell me how to add launch condition like if office 2007 present then install else do not, I will be able to complete my project if somebody help me to add launch condition.

So can you please tell me what should I do to create a single installer?

Comment: You should probably post the code from your Bundle.wxs so we have a chance at diagnosing this

Answer (score 0):

I Am also new to Wix. If You post your code It will be Helpful to solve your problem.  You can go through following approach it might help you.
Considering user have office 2007 installed on his system your installer should install only Add-Ins for 2007. and as you have executables for add-ins Bootstrapper is best approach for it.
For Conditional installation you first need to find which version of office is already installed.
This you can do using Registry Search

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id ="Office2007" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\InstallRoot::Path"/>
```

This will search in specific path.
Now for Installation

```
<ExePackage Id="2007Addin" SourceFile="your addin path"
        InstallCondition="(Office2007)"/>
```

There are many other useful arguments also. go through them.

Sample Program

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
<Bundle Name="WordAddin" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="NSS" UpgradeCode="51d04319-a135-487c-a4bb-aed77417bda7">
            <BootstrapperApplicationRefId="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

<util:RegistrySearchRef Id ='Office2007'/>

<--Here Install condition parameter checks if specific key is found if found installs packege -->
<--You can use NOT Office2007found this will install only if registry key not found-->
<Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id ="officeAddin" Compressed='yes' Cache='yes' Name='office addin' SourceFile='officeadd.msi' InstallCondition='Office2007found' DisplayInternalUI='yes'/>
</Chain>
</Bundle>

<!--Registry Search to find Which Office Version Is installed (incase registry search failed change keys according)-->
<Fragment>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="office2007" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0" Value="Version" Variable="Office2007found"/>
<--Below condition is only to check whether registry search is successful or not. remove it if not required-->
<bal:Condition Message="Failed to search regKey">Office2007found</bal:Condition>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

- For Your Reference

[wix installer 3.7 bootstrapper Registry search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219118/wix-installer-3-7-boostrapper-registry-search)
[How to detect installed version of MS-Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/how-to-detect-installed-version-of-ms-office)
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/installing-prerequisites-using-wix-bootstrapper-project-and/
[Launch Condition to Detect Office 2010 Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476809/launch-condition-to-detect-office-2010-applications)